# Хранение в массиве переменных

Tags: javascript

Могу ли я хранить в `games` для каждой игры свои переменные со значениями `id_game` и `href_game`?

```
var val = document.getElementById("game1").innerHTML;
var games = {
    'game1': game,
    'game2': game,
    'game3': game
};

games[game_name](val);

function game(val){
    console.log(val + ' ' + id_game + ' ' + href_game);
}
```

Как то так я представляю

```
var games = {
    'game1': game; var id_game = 1; var href_game = "game1.ru",
    'game2': game; var id_game = 2; var href_game = "game2.ru",
    'game3': game; var id_game = 3; var href_game = "game3.ru"
};
```

Чтобы функция game вывела мне `вывел 1 game1.ru`

Comment: Это основы, начните с изучения документации ... копайте в сторону объектов/вложенных объектов ..

Comment: Подход выбран ошибочный. Если функция одна и та же - нет смысла хранить ее в словаре. в этом случае хранить нужно как раз список параметров